# How do I send a weekly email from a list while keeping the group by sort?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a list of missionaries (teachers) and students. Students that are struggling are added to my list and I want to set up a weekly email that can be sent out to each missionary that shows who those students are. I have attached a snippet of what this looks like. Some missionaries have a lot of students that are struggling, and some only have a few. I want to know how I can send an email that is formatted such that a missionary only sees the students that are relevant to them, not the whole list.

Highlighted in Yellow are the missionary emails, which is what the list is grouped by. FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME is the student. In red would be the relevant students to that missionary email. PERSON_ID is the student ID, and EMPLOYEE_ID is the missionary ID. Let me know if you need any other additional information. I have access to the SharePoint Designer 2013 as well as the online version so a solution in either one works.

[image: Each missionary has a unique email. Highlighted in Yellow is the group by based off the the Missionary_Email field. Outlined in red is the student that is relevant to that specific email.]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Power Automate for your list. Add a trigger runs every week and send email according to the missionaries email column value.

Here is an exmaple:https://medium.com/@thomasgranheim/send-reminder-emails-using-microsoft-flow-and-office-365-606e0ea1565b

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automate-sending-weekly-reports/